# Master detail multiple levels inlaravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, relation

I have a table call `order`, that have a relation `hasMany` with other table call `details`, that have a relations `hasMany` with another one that i call `quantity`.

I need to get all records on `quantity` with the order `id` and all the records.

For example:

```
ID:1 order 1
      detail 1-order1: shirt
              quantity 23: detail1 -order1 : talla l - 15 - $23
              quantity 24: detail1 -order1 : talla s - 23 - $15
              quantity 25: detail1 -order1 : talla m - 5 - $10
```

Comment: Read Laravel [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 0):

**controller**

```
//gets all the necessary data
$orders = DB::table('order')->get();
$details = DB::table('detail')->get();
$quantities = DB::table('quantity')->get();

//Pass data to view
return view('your blade', ['orders' => $orders, 'details' => $details, 'quantities' => $quantities];
```

**blade**
I'm not sure how you want it to display but here is the general logic.

```
@forelse($orders as $order)
[call $order here]
   @forelse($details->where('order_id',$order->id) as $detail)
   [call $detail here]
       @forelse($quantities->where('detail_id', $detail->id) as $quantity)
       [call $quantity here]
       @empty
       @endforelse
   @empty
   @endforelse
@empty
@endforelse
```